# joining tables with same categories

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to join 2 tables with same categories but it's not quite working, its not returning results.

I have 2 tables tvshows and movies and both of them have columns categories now i want to go through all of them and see if categories match and return them but I don't know what is wrong with this. Please take a look, thanks!

```
$query = $connection->prepare("
    SELECT 
           a.id,
           a.hash,
           a.categories,
           a.thumb_location,
           a.name,
           a.year,
           b.id,
           b.hash,
           b.categories,
           b.thumb_location,
           b.name,
           b.year
           FROM movies AS a
           LEFT JOIN series AS b
           ON a.categories = b.categories
           WHERE a.categories LIKE ? OR b.categories LIKE ? ORDER BY a.id DESC
");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using column named `categories` in `WHERE` part of your query, but there are two columns with this name in tables `movies` and `series`, so database won't know, which column to search in.

You have to specify probably `WHERE a.categories LIKE ? OR b.categories LIKE ?` if you want to find rows, where some category is set for movie or series.

If you want to search for movies and series pairs by categories, you should join them by that column. But if categories is something like "Comedy,Action" etc. it won't work. You should consider remodeling database and create table `categories` and then `movies_categories` with ID of movie and ID of category rows and `series_categories` with same structure. Than you will be able to do lot's of queries for selecting movies that has categories same as series etc.

Comment: I have a specific db for categories, but when I insert a new movie in movie database it goes like Action Comedy Sci-fi, which works, but only when im doink LIKE ? on movies but when I start joining tables it kinda doesnt. Now i did like you suggested but still, it now returns like 1 movie title and 2 empty ones, code in edit

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood very well, but give this a try:

```
$query = $connection->prepare("
SELECT a.hash,
       a.categories,
       a.thumb_location,
       a.name,
       a.year,
       b.hash,
       b.categories,
       b.thumb_location,
       b.name,
       b.year
       FROM movies AS a
       LEFT JOIN series AS b
       ON a.hash = b.hash
       WHERE a.categories = b.categories ORDER BY id DESC
```

");